# What would be a more efficient approach to this Database?

Tags: mysql, database

I need a database that will allow me to group friends in my game. A friend can only have 1 friend. So it is a 1 to 1 relationship.

I can either build my database using two tables like this:

```
FriendA(name, id, friend_id)
FriendB(name, id, friend_id)
```

So `FriendA` keeps a reference to `FriendB` and vice versa.

---

OR

I can have one table that does something like this:

```
Person(name, id, friend_id)
```

---

**Which method is best?** To avoid opinions the answer must include some quantifiable aspects, such as which method will yield faster search results etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with the Person table, since the two tables would both be storing the same data if you end up having to search for a specific person later you'll start in one table then you'll have to search the other. This will waste some time because the longest search time is always when things aren't found.

Then if you stored both people in both tables then that's just storing redundant data which can lead to problems if you update a person in one table and then forget to update them in the other table

With the person table on the other hand everything is in one place and it's okay to have a table point to itself and you won't have any update anomalies from forgetting to update both tables. The search time should be faster as well because you don't need sql to go open up two tables.